# How do I remove an Outlook 365 Add-in?

Tags: office365, outlook-addin

How do I remove an Outlook 365 add-in from the desktop version of the software?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Go to the web version's options page, **https://outlook.office365.com/ecp**
2. Click on add-ins on the left
3. Click on the add-in
4. On the right side of the screen you will see a link to disable. **This also disables the add-in for the desktop version**.

Comment: Of course, this only disables the add-in. If you want to completely remove it, there is a trash can icon above the table of add-ins in this section labeled `Delete`.